# How to know the attributes defined for a type?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, attributes

I have defined a custom attribute and added it to a few classes. Know I'm using reflection to capture all types in the assembly. I want to filter out only the type that have this attribute defined.

I've seen the `Attributes` property for a Type object, but it returns only the values contained in a [specific enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeattributes%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

How can I retrieve types having a custom attribute defined?

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2010/05/16/retrieving-custom-attributes-using-reflection.aspx and http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/article.php/c6599/Taking-Advantage-of-Custom-Attributes-and-Reflection-to-Eliminate-A-Tedious-Task.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that:

```
object[] attributes = typeof(SomeType).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(YourAttribute), true);
```

But I prefer to use custom extension methods:

```
public static class ReflectionExtensions
{
    public static TAttribute GetAttribute<TAttribute>(this ICustomAttributeProvider obj, bool inherit)
        where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        return obj.GetAttributes<TAttribute>(inherit).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TAttribute> GetAttributes<TAttribute>(this ICustomAttributeProvider obj, bool inherit)
        where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        return obj.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (TAttribute), inherit).Cast<TAttribute>();
    }

    public static bool HasAttribute<TAttribute>(this ICustomAttributeProvider obj, bool inherit)
        where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        return obj.GetAttributes<TAttribute>(inherit).Any();
    }
}
```

(they work also for assemblies, methods, properties, etc, not just for types)

Comment: Shame on me, how did I miss that? :o