# Retrieve custom attributes of Type in .NET Standard

Tags: c#, custom-attributes, system.reflection, .net-standard

I'd like to use C#'s reflection and custom attributes to simplify registering a series of types with a central management class (i.e. it provides static methods taking a string key and invoking/retrieving the proper method/parameter for the associated type). Looking at other questions here and a couple places elsewhere, it seems like the best way of doing so is to simply iterate through all public types of the assembly -- since it's intended to be a library -- and check if each type has the proper attribute before adding the relevant values to the underlying Dictionaries. The reflection and iteration will definitely be slow, but I can live with it since it should only occur once.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to get an attribute from a type. For methods and assemblies, I can use `CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttribute<MyAttribute>(base)` from `System.Reflection.Extensions`, but that doesn't provide an overload for `Type`; the same for `Assembly.GetCustomAttribute(Assembly, Type)` and the `.IsDefined(...)` methods used in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1827310/962362). [Other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12091934/962362) [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16495917/962362) use methods on the `Type` itself that, from [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getcustomattributes.aspx), seem to be loaded from `mscorelib.dll`, but it didn't seem to be showing up in Intellisense even after adding the reference and I'm not sure how that .dll interacts with .NET Standard, anyway (as in, does it reduce the ability to run on arbitrary platforms at all?)

Am I missing something obvious, or is it really this hard to get an `Attribute` back off of a `Type`?

Comment: Can you show an example of how you try to call `GetCustomAttributes()`?

Comment: @RenéVogt That's what the `CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttribute<MyAttribute>(base)` was for (`base` is the `Type` I was trying to test), but I admit it could have been better signposted and include a bit more context. Either way, Connell's answer below worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `typeof(YourType).GetTypeInfo().GetCustomAttributes();`

Comment: Ah, that's got it! The `Info` in there is apparently quite important. Now my only question is why I wasn't seeing that in any of the other answers. Thanks!

Comment: It would work with GetType() in .net framework. GetTypeInfo() is required in .net core.

Comment: That makes sense. I love the mentality behind .NET Core and Standard, but I can't help but feel the documentation is a bit thin in places.

Comment: Indeed. this link explains some of the logic of removing the dependence of system.object on reflection. 

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/02/10/porting-to-net-core/